# C# Linq Char arrays Except() - Weird behavior

Tags: c#, linq

I am at a loss to understand why this Test would fail with Message **"Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<2>. Actual:<1>."**

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void Test()
        {
            char[] a1 = "abc".ToCharArray();
            char[] a2 = {'a', 'b', 'c', ' ', ' '};

            Assert.AreEqual(2, a2.Except(a1).Count());
        }
```

but the following would pass:

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void Test()
        {
            char[] a1 = "abc".ToCharArray();
            char[] a2 = {'a', 'b', 'c', ' ', 'd', ' '};

            Assert.AreEqual(2, a2.Except(a1).Count());
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because except finds difference of two sequences

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx

maybe you need something like this

```
var c=a2.Where(a=>a1.Contains(a)==false).Count();
```

Answer (score 5):

Except gives you a **SET** which means it does not return duplicates.

See [Except documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

The `Except` function returns the **set difference** of the two sequences - not the **difference**.

The space character only gets returned once.

Answer (score 3):

Except gives you a distinct list.

```
char[] a1 = "abc".ToCharArray();
char[] a2 = {'a', 'b', 'c', ' ', '1'};

Assert.AreEqual(2, a2.Except(a1).Count()); // Passes
```